# inetAddress.getByName(address) unknownhostexception

Tags: java, inetaddress, unknown-host

Does the `getByName()` function work on a link with a path like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`, or does the link have to include the host only (`https://stackoverflow.com`)?

I get `UnknownHostException` when I use a link that contains a "/", any tips on how to resolve that?

The console says the error lies here:

```
socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(adr), port);
```

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [InetAddress.getByName(String host)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-): *The host name can either be a machine name, such as "**`java.sun.com`**", or a textual representation of its IP address*. Only the **host name**, so `"stackoverflow.com"` in your case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`InetAddress.getByName` looks up a name (usually in DNS) and returns the corresponding address.

There's no host called "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" so that throws an UnknownHostException.
There's no host called "https://stackoverflow.com" either.
In this particular example, the host name is "stackoverflow.com".

If you want to parse a URL (such as "https://stackoverflow.com/questions") to get the hostname, you can use the `java.net.URL` class:

```
String hostname = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions").getHost();
System.out.println(hostname); // stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Thanks! But lets say someone just inputs stackoverflow.com, the URL.getHost wouldnt work as it needs a protocol, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @malikaasen No it wouldn't work as `new URL` needs a valid URL. Your program could try both formats and see if one works.